# Pegar trecho de uma string

Tags: c#, .net, string

quero pegar a palavra "kevingood120@gmail.com" que esta dentro desse MetroMessageBox

tentei isso, mas não deu certo:

```
String[] palavra = ex.Message.Split(new String[] { "(", ")" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não deu pra entender o que você quer fazer. Quer pegar a última informação no message box ou você tem o texto e quer ver se ele está contido na mensagem?

Comment: Se você quiser pegar o texto da message, provavelmente você vai ter que usar REGEX no que gera essa mensagem ai, é sempre dessa forma?

Comment: pessoal, é que tipo oq aparece no mesagebox é uma string, eu quero pegar o que esta entre parenteses nessa string, essa messagebox estou tratando o erro e nao quero que apareça isso, só quero que apareça o nome do campo que o usuario colocou.

Comment: E se tiver outra coisa entre parênteses?

Comment: lembrando oq estiver entre parenteses e uma palavra variada, sempre vai mudando....

Answer (score -1):

Não tem mistério, é só capturar o texto dentro dos parênteses.

Com regex

```
var s = Regex.Match(ex.Message, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Sem regex

```
string output = ex.Message.Split('(', ')')[1];
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b76LZF)