# Obter só um trecho da string em C#

Tags: c#

Tentei por substring sem sucesso, obter somente o texto depois do segundo ":".

> :##########!#######@############### PRIVMSG #barbosza :ds

Por questões de segurança ocultei alguns caracteres com #.

Comment: Tenho certeza que isto já foi respondido antes, provavelmente algumas vezes. Vou tentar achar a duplicata para fechar.

Comment: Outras http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35400/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103038/101